# Npgsql: In C#, which is more efficient

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have 8 columns and about 500k rows of data to return.

I would like to pass the DataTable back to the calling function.

Which of these methods should be the mose efficient to use:

```
using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();

    using (NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
}
```

Or

```
using NpgsqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

dataTable.Load(reader);
```

Obviously the second option looks much cleaner but which will give better performance?

Comment: Assuming the query itself is not that complex (say, not 100 tables joined with one another) fetching (either `adapter.Fill` or `dataTable.Load`) is the most expensive operation here. Are you sure you want to load all the 500k records without filtering or processing them on database side (stored procedures and the like)?

Comment: Why don't you just measure? That should be both easier and more accurate than asking random people on the internet.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, I need the full 500k as they contain names and email addresses for email which need to be sent.

Comment: @JonasH, I did a test and it seems the longest running line of the first code is on the line using (NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd)) and on the second code dataTable.Load(reader);. I'm connecting from a remote location so the network speed is a lot lower and once the code is deployed, the network speed shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: If you actually care about performance, I'd advise avoiding DataTable altogether - read directly from NpgsqlDataReader instead. This would allow streaming row-by-row, as opposed to the DataTable approach which keeps the entire resultset in memory.

Comment: @ShayRojansky, would you pass NpgsqlDataReader between functions? I was concerned that if I return the NpgsqlDataReader from the function, it might not be disposed of properly?

Comment: Sure, but you have to take care that ownership is clearly understood, i.e. exactly who's role it is to dispose the reader at the end. In any case, I wouldn't load a huge set of data into memory just to avoid the disposal problem.